# Can I use template parameter as argument to non-template method?

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking to move some of the code of within a template method to a non-template method in order to decrease the binary size.

There is a template class called 'Target', as illustrated below

```
template<TargetType K, typename V = plat_target_handle_t>
class Target
{
   .............
   ..............
};
```

TargetType is an enum data type.

```
template<>
template< TargetType T>
std::vector<Target<T> >
Target<TARGET_TYPE_X>::getChildren(const TargetState i_state) const
{
    std::vector<Target<T> > l_children;
    for ( int i=0; i < elements_in_some_list ; ++i)
    {
       /*If the current entry in some_list  match my critera, add to the l_children */
    }
}
```

TargetType is an enum data type and TARGET_TYPE_X is one of the enum values.

I want to move all the logic to select the children to a global method, lets say getChildrenHelper.

getChildrenHelper is declared as below.

```
void  getGhildrenHelper(const TargetType i_targetType,
      const TargetState i_targetstate,
     std::vector<Target<TARGET_TYPE_ALL>> & io_children);
```

And then the getChildren method would eventually look like

```
template<>
template< TargetType T>
std::vector<Target<T> >
Target<TARGET_TYPE_X>::getChildren(const TargetState i_state) const
{
    std::vector<Target<T> > l_children;
    childHelper(T,i_state,l_children);

     return l_children;
}
```

My guess is this cannot be done, though the native compiler that I am working with did not through an error.

However there is another existing code where the similar concept is working  perfectly fine

```
template< TargetType K >
inline ReturnCode putParam(const Target<K>& i_target,
const RingID i_ringID,
const RingMode i_ringMode)
{
ReturnCode l_rc = FAPI2_RC_SUCCESS;

// Find the string in the SEEPROM
l_rc = findInImageAndApply(i_target, i_ringID, i_ringMode);

return l_rc;
}


fapi2::ReturnCode findImageAndApply(
  const fapi2::Target<fapi2::TARGET_TYPE_ALL>& i_target,
  const RingID i_ringID,
  const fapi2::RingMode i_ringMode)
{
 ................
................
}
```

Comment: Your example program that you wish to refactor does not compile. The definitions of `TargetType`, `TARGET_TYPE_X`, `TargetState` and  `plat_target_handle_t` are missing.

Comment: TargetType and TargetState are enums,  I have non elaborated on them, similarly plat_target_handle_t is defines somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common for template functions to invoke ordinary, non-template functions in order to execute a large chunk of code that does not need or use any template parameters. This is a common technique for avoiding template-generated code bloat.

In your case, `TargetType` appears is a template parameter, and there is no such class. As such:

```
void  getGhildrenHelper(const TargetType i_targetType,
      const TargetState i_targetstate,
     std::vector<Target<TARGET_TYPE_ALL>> & io_children);
```

that by itself should not compile, since `TargetType` appears to be a template parameter, and not a class name, based on the code in your template specialization.

But, your code might be ambiguous, here. In any case, if neither `TargetType` and `TargetState`, nor `Target<TARGET_TYPE_ALL>` are template parameters, this would make this an ordinary function, and it can certainly be invoked from a template function, with matching parameters.

A template function can do anything that an ordinary function does, including calling other functions, or using other templates. The requirements are the same as for any other function: matching function parameter types, etc...

Comment: Sam, Thanks for the answer, however what do you mean by 'template parameter and not a class name',  can you pls. elaborate on that?

Comment: You can answer this question yourself: is `TargetType` a template parameter, or a name of an actual class?

Comment: Oh.. I guess I misunderstood it earlier , it is template parameter.

Comment: Then this cannot be a regular function. It can only be another template function.

Comment: I am forced to re-think about this answer , in the above example template parameter 'T'  should get replaced by the actual argument  to the actual argument from the point of call.  From that point onward why I cannot use that as a specific type.  In the above case 'TargetType' is a template parameter but it is an enum as well.

Comment: What happens with the template parameters of the `getChildren` template function has no bearing, whatsoever, on some other function.